# Connection property has not been initialized Error (ExecuteNonQuery)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

This question has been addressed all over the web and I tried a lot of things without success.  The SQL EXPRESS service is setup to accept local system account but the problem still exists.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="PhoneTemplateChange" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PhoneTemplateChange;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

I created a class to do database operations in the constructor I have

```
_connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhoneTemplateChange"].ConnectionString;
```

and a method in this class to insert data

```
 public void AddNewChangeOrder(int operation, int targetExt)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "INSERT into [dbo].ChangeOrder (operation, targetExt, dtrequested) VALUES (@operation, @targetExt, @dtrequested)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
            {
                try
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operation", operation);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@targetExt", targetExt);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dtrequested", DateTime.Now);
                    //con.CreateCommand();
                    con.Open();
                    //cmd.InitializeLifetimeService();
                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have played around with the connection string trying all different suggestions, also the commented code in the method above is what I tried to solve the problem. Still no luck!

I also changed the connection string I get two different exceptions this way

```
 Database=PhoneTemplateChange
```

The above gives the exception in the title.
And the following gives the Exception "Cannot open Database PhoneTemplatechange.mdf requested by the login. Login failed for user 'mydomain\myusername'"

```
 Database=PhoneTemplateChange.mdf
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ask yourself one question Where have you assigned your application any connection ??You have declared but you command does not not know which connection to use . try this **SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con)** ,Please do not take my words offensive but finding reason will help you . Or You can tell your command to use this connection this way also **cmd.Connection = con;**

Comment: yes I realized this! and thanks a lot for the explanation again that's what I like to hear! Sometimes you miss simple things and you bang your head trying to figure it out and it will be right in front of you!

Comment: Always good to get a second set of eyes on it when thetre's an issue.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the line of code where you specify that `cmd` uses `con` as it's connection.  As a result the Command (cmd) has no connection, and con isn't associated with any command at all.

Add this line before executing:

```
cmd.Connection - con;
```

Alternatively (and better IMO) change your using statement as follows:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
```